# How to make overlay scale with image

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/L9xnzqo8/7/

I need the overlay to always be on top of the image no matter what the screen is resized to.

I tries using JS but it doesn't work:

```
var width = $('.showreel-img').width();
console.log(width);
document.getElementById("video-overlay").style.width = width;
```

Comment: share the correct fiddle

Comment: That is the correct fiddle

Comment: problem is quite vague, try inserting more detail mate

Comment: Hard to test your fiddle as the images are not loading

Comment: All I basically want to do is make the width 1.5 times the height at all times?